# SNMP for application monitoring on server

Tags: networking, snmp

My objective is to use SNMP to monitor applications running on my servers/systems connected on my network; applications such as  MySQL Sever, Apache Tomcat, Trend Micro Antivirus, TeamViewer. Could anyone suggest where I can download MIB files for these applications. Please do suggest methods other than SNMP that I can use to monitor applications. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you choose SNMP? Many application vendors no longer support SNMP as a monitoring approach, and you have to check each vendors' documentation to see which are he supported methods.

Comment: I have read on other sources that SNMP support has been withdrawn for few applications like MS SQL SERVER 2005. But most websites still say SNMP is the most widely used protocol for network management. Commercial products also still incorporate SNMP. What alternatives to SNMP would you suggest?  I would like to mention that I am an amateur working with network management methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt if today you can still find a one-ring-to-rule-them-all way to talk to and monitor multiple applications, as different products might only have a few options, and it might be impossible to find a common way. If you check commercial tools such as Microsoft System Center Operation Manager, it uses different protocols for different products, which is more feasible to go.

Comment: True. That's what I was thinking. I have already started working with SNMP. WIll soon work with WMI to monitor applications such as Windows Defender. Thanks for your help.